# Difference between these two Continuous Wavelet Transforms?

Tags: fft, python, continuous-signals, wavelet, transform

I am porting [Synchrosqueezing](https://github.com/ebrevdo/synchrosqueezing) to [Python](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy), and came across an implementation difference on CWT between mine and [PyWavelets'](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt) - details below. The idea is to merge this implementation to PyWavelets if latter doesn't already have it, but I cannot explain the difference as I'm unfamiliar with wavelet transforms.

What is each implementation trying to accomplish, and what are some key differences?

---

[Full post](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/issues/543#issuecomment-614974001); comparing [`pywt.cwt`](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/master/pywt/_cwt.py#L37) vs. [`cwt_fwd`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/blob/master/ssqueezepy/wavelet_transforms.py#L389), pasting transform excerpts:

```
# pywt.cwt
for i, scale in enumerate(scales):
    step = x[1] - x[0]
    j = np.arange(scale * (x[-1] - x[0]) + 1) / (scale * step)
    j = j.astype(int)  # floor
    if j[-1] >= int_psi.size:
        j = np.extract(j < int_psi.size, j)
    int_psi_scale = int_psi[j][::-1]

    size_scale = next_fast_len(
        data.shape[-1] + int_psi_scale.size - 1
    )
    if size_scale != size_scale0:
        # Must recompute fft_data when the padding size changes.
        fft_data = fftmodule.fft(data, size_scale, axis=-1)
    size_scale0 = size_scale
    fft_wav = fftmodule.fft(int_psi_scale, size_scale, axis=-1)
    conv = fftmodule.ifft(fft_wav * fft_data, axis=-1)
    conv = conv[..., :data.shape[-1] + int_psi_scale.size - 1]
```

```
# cwt_fwd
xh = np.fft.fft(x)  # x == data
xi = np.zeros((1, N))
psihfn = wfiltfn(wavelet_type, opts)

for ai in range(na):
    a = Wx_scales[ai]
    psih = psihfn(a * xi) * np.sqrt(a) / np.sqrt(2 *PI) * (-1)**k
    dpsih = (1j * xi / opts['dt']) * psih

    xcpsi = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(psih * xh))
    Wx[ai] = xcpsi

    dxcpsi = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(dpsih * xh))
    dWx[ai] = dxcpsi
```

---

**Observations**:

- `cwt_fwd` has an imaginary component, `pywt.cwt` doesn't
- `pywt.cwt`'s norm is ~10x greater (see `norm_abs`) [in 'full post']
- The signal (`x`) preprocessing seems to undo itself in this case as evident in vs. Unprocessed
- `pywt.cwt` handles the noisy signal (`sN`) case considerably differently in the upper-half

---

**Visualized differences**:

[image]